# Linked List OCaml

Tags: ocaml, data-structures

How would I create a linked list to hold my data in OCaml? I'm trying to make a singly linked list, however I'm having trouble with the syntax. I just want to make a module to simply get the 'a from the linked list, insert 'a or delete 'a.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is this homework by any chance? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: Its not really homework, just reading a book on data structures and wanted to try to implement this in Ocaml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As aneccodeal told, ocaml already has lists.

However, for your interest, this is how you could build your own list. Obviously, you would never use it on a real application :) If you want to have some trees, the data structure would be very similar.

```
exception Empty_list

type 'a my_list = Nil | List of 'a * 'a my_list

let head = function 
     Nil -> raise Empty_list
   | List(e,_) -> e;;

let tail = function
    Nil -> Nil
   | List(_,t) -> t

let l = List(1, List(4, List(8, Nil)));;

print_endline (string_of_int(head l));;

print_endline (string_of_int (head(tail l)));;
```

Answer (score 5):

OCaml has lists built in:

List of integers:
[1;2;3;4;5] ;;
  returns: int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]

List of Strings: 
["this";"that";"other"];;
  returns: string list = ["this"; "that"; "other"]

Or you can use the cons operator :: to build lists:

1::2::3::[];;
  returns: int list = [1; 2; 3]

To get the head (first item) of a list:

List.hd [1;2;3]
returns 1

To get the tail of a list (all items after the first item)

List.tl [1;2;3]
returns: int list = [2; 3]

Also, you can have a look at how lists are implemented in the OCaml standard library by looking at:

[installation location for OCaml]/lib/ocaml/std-lib/list.ml

Comment: Does that however qualify as a LinkedList, with Nodes and etc?

Comment: @Failsal: yes. Although its really a stack (a data structure built from a linked list), so you can only push and pop nodes from the front of the list.

Comment: Just added this at the end of my answer: you can have a look at how lists are implemented in the OCaml standard library by looking at:

[installation location for OCaml]/lib/ocaml/std-lib/list.ml

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't OCaml already have lists as a primitive?  I haven't done SML since college, but I seem to recall `head` and `tail` primitives.  I see that other people have implemented a true linked list data structure out there though... check out [Dustin's OCaml Linkedlist](http://bleu.west.spy.net/~dustin/projects/ocaml/doc/Linkedlist.html) for example.